# How to get past data entries in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to upload some data daily into the firebase storage. I must be able to retrieve them when I need by the filtering by the date. How to get this done?

Comment: Detail out your requirement and where you are getting struck. Make sure you include code/config snippets which you have already tried. SO won't help unless there's any existing effort on your part

Comment: I suggest you to make one of the keys a time. Then you can filter it by given interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving daily upload is using the [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager) for pre-lollipop devices, otherwise try using [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler). These are better for battery's lifetime.

1. Register new application at [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and follow instructions about implementing firebase in your Android app.
2. Add the Cloud Firestore Android library to your `app/build.gradle` module file:

   - `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'`
3. Initialize an instance of Cloud Firestore:

   - `FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();`
4. Add data to Firestore:

   ```
   Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
   data.put("name", "Joe");
   data.put("date", date);

   db.collection("users")
           .add(data)
           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                   // success
               }
           })
           .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                   // error
               }
           });
   ```
5. Retrieve by date (see [filtering options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)):

   ```
   Query query = db
        .collection("users")
        .whereEqualTo("date", new Date())
   query
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            // ...
        });
   ```

Hope I helped somehow :)

Comment: thank you!!! i will try this out and let you know